# The TestContext.TestName property NEVER changes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

**GOAL:**

I want to use the TestContext.TestName property to extract the name of the test being ran so that my [TestCleanup] function can log the outcome to our bespoke results repository, automatically when every test completes.

**PROBLEM:**

Even in my basic 'sanity check' test project that contains 5 tests that are similar to the structure below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethodX()
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("In Test '{0}'",_ctx.TestName));
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

With a Class 'initializer' like below which sets _ctx for me:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInit(TestContext Context)
{
    _ctx = Context;
    Console.WriteLine("In ClassInit()");
}
```

<sub>[[NOTE: the Console.WriteLines are purely there for me to hover the mouse over and inspect value/properties, etc.]]</sub>

The `_ctx.TestName` NEVER changes from the name of the first test in the run of tests, i.e. If I was to run all five tests ('TestMethod1', 'TestMethod2', 'TestMethod3', etc.) they all log 'TestMethod1' as their testname in my results repository.
Running the tests individually it works fine, but that is of no use to me as I need to be able to run 10's/100's/1000's of tests against my application and have the testContext handle the testname or me.

I have tried this several times now and searched the internet loads and haven't anyone else with this problem, so i'm either: unique with this problem, have poor 'Google-Fu' skills, or am doing something REAL stupid.  Hopefully this makes sense and someone has the answer.

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is happening because the `[ClassInitialize]` is executed only once for the whole test run and you initialize the `_ctx` in there. Use the `[TestInitialize]` instead, which is executed before each test method and override the [TestContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) :

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
    
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Runs once before each test method and logs the method's name
        Console.WriteLine(TestContext.TestName);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Logs the method name inside the method
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("In Test '{0}'", TestContext.TestName));
    }

    // ... Your rest test methods here
}
```

Comment: I got similar problem, then I simply changed the `ClassInitialize` to `TestInitialize` taking the context as parameter. It compiles but the test tells the `TestInitialize` method is using wrong signature (it cannot accept a parameter).

Why on Earth the `ClassInitialize`will take a context if that's supposed to be bound to test method and not entire class? Why the `TestInitialize` doesn't accept a context? If `ClassInitialize` takes a `TestContext` as a parameter, how can we guess that we need to add a property?

Unbelievably non-intuitive.

Comment: How do you initialize the TestContext? I have to assume you are getting a NullReferenceException at Console.WriteLine(TestContext.TestName); in Initialize()

Comment: Answer I found out: You don't.                               IFF you name it "TestContext" <-- BOLD UNDERLINE not Context, MyContext, anything else THEN the framework will assign an instance of TestContext before TestInitialize.

Comment: That worked perfectly! But I second the sentiments by @fernacolo This is a bad design. What's more, if you don't make the TestContext property public, you test class will be silently ignored with no warnings/errors whatsoever. This *must* be done exactly as Schaliasos says.

Comment: Thanks @Gary... for mstest you literally just have to add the property ```public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }``` to a class and it magically gets populated properly for each test. no need for any TestInitialize or ClassInitialize or trying to capture the TestContext manually. Just magic. mind boggling that this isn't documented anywhere!!!

Answer (score -1):

MSTest.exe outputs can be configured to output a .trx (xml)file with the complete results of you test, names , passed or failed and output from any of those test, there is also a tool to convert the TRX file to HTML http://trxtohtml.codeplex.com/

Hope this helps